# Saving data to the another directory from where the current python code is running

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know if there is a way to save data to the another directory from the current working directory where the script is running?

below is the part of the script that generates new data "integ = pd.DataFrame(list)" based on the files in the current working directory, I want to save the data to the another folder where the integrated data should be saved.

Current working directory is :
path = 'C:/Users/sidik/Desktop/py/measurements/18082020/BS3023'
the subfolder where the integrated data should be saved:
eval = 'C:/Users/sidik/Desktop/py/measurements/18082020/eval/BS3023'.

"""

```
if file[:6] == sample and file[16:18] == power:          # select sample names and power values (1 to 10) [16:18] power  10
    print(file)
    data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='.', delimiter='\t', skiprows=13, header=None)  #thousands='.'
    idx_min = abs(data[0] - min).values.argmin()  # find the index of max and min values
    idx_max = abs(data[0] - max).values.argmin()
    integration = data.iloc[idx_max:idx_min, 1].sum().astype(str)
    list.append(integration)
    # make a text file in the folder
    integ = pd.DataFrame(list)
    integ.to_csv('Integration_'+ sample+'_power_' + power +'.txt',index=None, header=False)
    print(integration)
    # plot 
    arr_x = np.array(data[0])
    arr_y = np.array(data[1])
    array_x = np.append(array_x, [arr_x], axis=0)
    array_y = np.append(array_y, [arr_y], axis=0)
```

"""

Comment: look into `pathlib` or `os`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
integ.to_csv(f'path/to/folder/Integration_{sample}_power_{power}.txt', index=None, header=False)
```

Comment: it does not help!

Comment: repalce `path/to/folder` by the path to your desired directory

Comment: sure, I did that.

Comment: It should work. Have you an error message or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the full path:

```
integ.to_csv('C:/Users/example/dir/path/' + 'Integration_'+ sample+'_power_' + power +'.txt',index=None, header=False)
```

Comment: it does not work, it simply concatenates the sub folder name to the created text file, and file is saved in current working directory

Comment: no screenshot ,this is created file name BS2315Integration_BS2482_power_10.txt